# Fork () OS . 4 hi coming in output expecting 3 hi

Tags: fork

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
      if(fork()==0)
          printf("Hi");
```

I am expecting 3 hi and getting 4 hi 
SO i edited the `printf` as `printf("Hi %d %d %d ",i,getpid(),getppid());`
The first child created prints two hi with same value of I i.e 0 and its pid and parent's pid are also same. Why?

Comment: Which OS? I have 3 under OS X.

Comment: I use Ubuntu . You can try online terminal also

Answer (score 1):

It's quite interesting and looks like the answer is output buffering. For example we have:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    if(fork()==0) {
      printf("Hi %d %d %d\n",i,getpid(),getppid());
    }
  }
}
```

If run this code in terminal there will be 3 lines, but if I will redirect the output to less there will be four!

If we will flush the buffer after printf() the problem will disappear:

```
  // ...
  printf("Hi %d %d %d\n",i,getpid(),getppid());
  fflush(stdout);
  // ...
```

That's happening because stdout is buffered, so when process forked the buffer still not flushed.

From `man stdout`:

> The  stream  stderr  is  unbuffered.   The stream stdout is
>   line-buffered when it points to a terminal.  Partial lines will not
>   appear until fflush(3) or exit(3) is called, or a newline is printed. 
>   This can produce  unexpected  results,  especially  with  debugging 
>   output.